# TypeError: filter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v'

Tags: python, signal-processing

I am trying to create a digital filter in Python to filter a wave file.

It is telling me that i'm not passing an argument to the filter function, but I am as part of the loop at the bottom.

TypeError: filter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'v'

Can anyone assist please?

```
import scipy.io.wavfile as wavfile
import numpy as np


#Load the data 
r, x = wavfile.read('M80_and_speech.wav')

#create output array
y = np.zeros(len(x))

#filter coefficients
a1 = -1.96977856
a2 = 0.97022848
b0 = 0.98500176
b1 = -1.97000352
b2 = 0.98500176

#create filter class
class IIR2Filter:
    def __init__(self, a1, a2, b0, b1, b2):
        self.input_acc = 0
        self.outut_acc = 0
        self.buffer1 = 0
        self.buffer2 = 0


    def filter(self, v):
        #accumulator for the IIR part
        self.input_acc = v
        self.input_acc = self.input_acc - (a1*self.buffer1)
        self.input_acc = self.input_acc - (a2*self.buffer2)
        #accumulator for the FIR part
        self.output_acc = self.input_acc * b0
        self.output_acc = self.output_acc + (b1*self.buffer1)
        self.output_acc = self.output_acc + (b2*self.buffer2)

        self.buffer2 = self.buffer1
        self.buffer1 = self.input_acc

        return self.output_acc

for i in range (len(x)):
    y[i] = IIR2Filter.filter(x[i])
```

Comment: Your `filter` method takes two arguments.  The first, `self` is an instance of the `IIR2Filter` class.  `f = IIR2Filter(...); f.filter(x[i])` is syntactic sugar for `f = IIR2Filter(...); IIR2Filter.filter(f, x[i])`

Comment: Create an instance first (`instance = IIR2Filter()`) and then call the method on the instance (`instance.filter(x[i])`). Note that instead of `for i in range(len(x)): y[i] = IIR2Filter.filter(x[i])` you generally use `for i, value in enumerate(x): y[i] = instance(value)` or use a list comprehension and convert it to an array later: `y = [instance(v) for v in x]; y = np.array(y)`.

Comment: `class IIR2Filter` defines a class.  You need to call filter on an instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks everyone, your comments are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven’t initialised the class (`IIR2Filter`), so `filter(self, v)` is not being passed `self`; `x[i]` is therefore the first positional argument (`self`) and the second positional argument (`v`) is missing.

Also, the arguments you’ve added to the `__init__` method shadow the variable names in the global scope (those at the top of the module). It looks like your `filter` method intends to reference the global variables; the arguments on `__init__` are superfluous.

Comment: No problem! Feel free to accept the answer as correct :-)